# Popup window in asp.net mvc

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

How to remove the menu part when the modal window pops up, and so that only the forms for inserting information remain. My code works fine. but when I press Edit button, it popups like the whole window with nav bar.

My Edit controller (Entity Framevork):

```
    // GET: Products/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.FK_CATEGORY = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CATEGORY_ID",  "CATEGORY_NAME", product.FK_CATEGORY);
        return View(product);
    }

    // POST: Products/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "PRODUCT_ID,PRODUCT_NAME,FK_CATEGORY")] Product product)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.FK_CATEGORY = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CATEGORY_ID", "CATEGORY_NAME", product.FK_CATEGORY);
        return View(product);
    }
```

My Edit PartialView:
@model MyNewApp5.Models.Product

```
         <div class="modal-header">
               <h4 class="modal-title">Edit product</h4>
         </div>

         <!-- Modal body -->
         <div class="modal-body" id="editform">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Products", FormMethod.Post, new { @id =    "formsubmit" }))
         {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PRODUCT_ID)

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PRODUCT_NAME, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PRODUCT_NAME, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PRODUCT_NAME, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FK_CATEGORY, "FK_CATEGORY", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("FK_CATEGORY", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FK_CATEGORY, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

And my Index:

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" data-url="@Url.Action("CreatePartialView", "Products")">

  </div>


  <script>
      function editBut() {
    $('.btn-success').click(function () {
        var url = $('#myModalEdit').data('url');
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $("#myModalEdit").html(data);
            $("#myModalEdit").modal('show');
        });
    });
}
  </script>


  <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Products", new { id = item.PRODUCT_ID })" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalEdit" onclick="editBut()">Edit</a> |
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
// Open modal in AJAX callback
$('btn-success').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.blur(); // Manually remove focus from clicked link.
  var url = $('#myModalEdit').data('url')
  $.get(url, function(html) {
    $(html).appendTo('body').modal();
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- AJAX response must be wrapped in the modal's root class. -->
<div class="modal">
</div>
```

it's taken from https://jquerymodal.com/ - Example 4: AJAX

I hope this helps